# RemoveAllListeners() does not delete $events attribute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I built a simple clientside logger which prints all current active socket.io listeners on my page. I'm getting this information directly from the *socket* object and the inner *$events* object.

The $events object looks like this for example in chrome:

```
$events: Object
    news: function (data) {
    __proto__: Object
```

But when the listener for the event is removed with *socket.removeAllListeners('news')* then it looks like this:

```
$events: Object
    news: null
    __proto__: Object
```

The attributes stays but gets *null* as value. Why is it not deleted completely?

When you use *socket.once()* and get the one emit from the server or when you delete the concrete listener directly with *socket.removeListener()* the attribute gets deleted and it looks like this:

```
$events: Object
    __proto__: Object
```

I would really like to know why it is behaving this way. Is it still listening for the events with null as value but without calling any function?

Comment: Whenever an event occurs on an object for a particular event type, Node needs to manually look up that type to see if there are any functions associated. Doesn't really matter if the property for that event type exists with `null`, or if the property doesn't exist *(making it `undefined`)*. Either way, Node sees that there's no function, so there's no handler to invoke.

Comment: One reason not to delete properties is that it is slower that using `null` because V8 uses hidden classes for optimizing object access, but it is hard to say without asking the socketio authors. It is also just be easier to have a defined structure and not constantly toggle the existing properties.